# YAML is data-oriented, rather than document markup. What does it means?

Tags: yaml

I read in Wikipedia that YAML is data-oriented, rather than document markup. 
What does it means?

What is data-oriented vs document markup document?

Answer (score 0):

Markup languages deal with adding attributes to text.   The special characters deal with things like bold, italics, or even hyperlinks.

Yaml on the other hand does none of these things.   It allows you to create text files which represent structured information.  The special characters deal with delimiting arrays, dictionaries, objects, and how to represent specific data types like integers and strings.